# ECMAScript 5.1 mobile compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, ios, mobile

Where can I find useful information about compatibility  of ECMAScript 5.1 with mobile devices browsers?

Comment: Not aware of a compiled list, but you can check on your own devices with [es5-compat-table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) or use a polyfill, such as [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), to cover for most of any lack of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching for the same q&a and came across this website

http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

it includes "webkit" as a column which, I believe, all (most) of the mobile web browsers are based upon.

Answer (score 1):

Older mobile device browsers don't support ECMA5 extensively. For example, Android 2.3 and iOS Safari 4.3 doesn't support ECMA5 script mode: http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict.